# Looping through a long string and uploading to SQL - Python

Tags: python, sql, credentials

I have been wracking my head about this one for about 2 weeks and can't seem to get my head around a method to do this.

I have been tasked with creating a script that can get the cached credentials of a machine and upload that data to an SQL database.
I have had a look at all the major tools, mimikatz etc. But for the time being, I am just working with the basic Command Prompt command, "cmdkey.exe /list"
This command is called using the "subprocess" module and I can get the data perfectly fine but the issue is that the output returns an one entire string.

Without providing the sensitive data that is returned, this is the structure of the data:

Target: ...
Type: ...
User: ...
~Note about the entry~

I have been able to loop through the string line by line, using the built in "split" function. I created a function, that added the value of the line to a different list depending on whether it contained a particular string, e.g. "Target: ". This didn't work correctly due to the final note, not having a title.

Another problem that I have is that some entries have all 4 fields, where as some entries only have 2 fields so I can't just loop through line by line and add each line to a different list one by one.

I have been able to set each line to a count, e.g

```
0    Target: 
1    Type: Domain Extended Credentials
2    User: 
3    Saved for this logon only
4
0    Target: 
1    Type: Generic
2    Local machine persistence
3
```

As you can see, due to the differences in what data is shown for each "block", the line counts don't match up.

Not so much a specific bit of code that is troubling me, its more the method.

This is how I am calling the "cmdkey.exe /list" command.

```
command = ['cmdkey.exe', '/list']
result = run(command, stdout=PIPE, stderr=PIPE, universal_newlines=True)
r = result.stdout
formatted = r.split("\n", 3)[-1]
```

Basically, what I am looking to do it loop through a string line by line and add that line to a list depending on the field heading. If there is no with that heading, add a blank value.

I know this is very vague but after searching for ways of completing this, I have struggled to find methods to accomplish this. On that note, any advice on other ways of accomplishing this would be greatly appreciated as well.

As requested in the comments, adding the data I am working with, edited to remove the sensitive data:

```
Target: MicrosoftAccount:target=SSO_POP_Device
Type: Domain Extended Credentials
User: username
Saved for this logon only

Target: MicrosoftAccount:target=SSO_POP_Device
Type: Generic
Local machine persistence

Target: MicrosoftAccount:target=SSO_POP_Device
Type: Domain Password
User: domain\username
Local machine persistence

Target: LegacyGeneric:target=Slack/tokens
Type: Generic
User: tokens
Local machine persistence

Target: MicrosoftAccount:target=SSO_POP_Device
Type: Generic
Local machine persistence

Target: MicrosoftAccount:target=SSO_POP_Device
Type: Generic
User: domain\username
Local machine persistence

Target: MicrosoftAccount:target=SSO_POP_Device
Type: Generic
User: username token
Local machine persistence

Target: MicrosoftAccount:target=SSO_POP_Device
Type: Generic
Local machine persistence

Target: MicrosoftAccount:target=SSO_POP_Device
Type: Generic
User: username
Local machine persistence

Target: MicrosoftAccount:target=SSO_POP_Device
Type: Generic
User: username
Local machine persistence

Target: MicrosoftAccount:target=SSO_POP_Device
Type: Generic
User: domain\username

Target: MicrosoftAccount:target=SSO_POP_Device
Type: Generic
User: email address

Target: MicrosoftAccount:target=SSO_POP_Device
Type: Generic Certificate
User: <Certificate>

Target: MicrosoftAccount:target=SSO_POP_Device
Type: Generic

Target: MicrosoftAccount:target=SSO_POP_Device   
Type: Generic
```

Comment: Can you give us at least a template that looks like your string ? To me, it looks like you need to use `str.split('\n\n')` so that you can have a list of **groups**. Then, in your list of groups, you can use `str.split('\n')` to separate by each line in a given group.

Comment: Thanks for the reply.

Adding the template to my original post as can't format it properly in the comments.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You could read the data into a dictionary like in this example shown:

```
def empty():
    return {'Target': '', 'Type': '', 'User': '', 'Comment': ''}


def process(record):
    item = empty()

    for line in record:
        line_items = line.split(':', 1)
        if len(line_items) == 2:
            item[line_items[0]] = line_items[1].strip()
        if len(line_items) == 1:
            item['Comment'] = line_items[0].strip()

    print('here save into SQL:')
    print('  Target:' + item['Target'])
    print('  Type:' + item['Type'])
    print('  User:' + item['User'])
    print('  Comment:' + item['Comment'])
    print('')


def main():
    lines = r.split('\n')

    record = []
    for line in lines:
        line = line.strip()
        if line != '':
            record.append(line)
        else:
            process(record)
            record = []

    process(record)


if __name__ == "__main__":
    main()
```

Result would be:

```
here save into SQL:
  Target:MicrosoftAccount:target=SSO_POP_Device
  Type:Domain Extended Credentials
  User:username
  Comment:Saved for this logon only

here save into SQL:
  Target:MicrosoftAccount:target=SSO_POP_Device
  Type:Generic
  User:
  Comment:Local machine persistence

here save into SQL:
  Target:MicrosoftAccount:target=SSO_POP_Device
  Type:Domain Password
  User:domain\username
  Comment:Local machine persistence

here save into SQL:
  Target:LegacyGeneric:target=Slack/tokens
  Type:Generic
  User:tokens
  Comment:Local machine persistence

here save into SQL:
  Target:MicrosoftAccount:target=SSO_POP_Device
  Type:Generic
  User:
  Comment:Local machine persistence

here save into SQL:
  Target:MicrosoftAccount:target=SSO_POP_Device
  Type:Generic
  User:domain\username
  Comment:Local machine persistence

here save into SQL:
  Target:MicrosoftAccount:target=SSO_POP_Device
  Type:Generic
  User:username token
  Comment:Local machine persistence

here save into SQL:
  Target:MicrosoftAccount:target=SSO_POP_Device
  Type:Generic
  User:
  Comment:Local machine persistence

here save into SQL:
  Target:MicrosoftAccount:target=SSO_POP_Device
  Type:Generic
  User:username
  Comment:Local machine persistence

here save into SQL:
  Target:MicrosoftAccount:target=SSO_POP_Device
  Type:Generic
  User:username
  Comment:Local machine persistence

here save into SQL:
  Target:MicrosoftAccount:target=SSO_POP_Device
  Type:Generic
  User:domain\username
  Comment:

here save into SQL:
  Target:MicrosoftAccount:target=SSO_POP_Device
  Type:Generic
  User:email address
  Comment:

here save into SQL:
  Target:MicrosoftAccount:target=SSO_POP_Device
  Type:Generic Certificate
  User:<Certificate>
  Comment:

here save into SQL:
  Target:MicrosoftAccount:target=SSO_POP_Device
  Type:Generic
  User:
  Comment:

here save into SQL:
  Target:MicrosoftAccount:target=SSO_POP_Device
  Type:Generic
  User:
  Comment:
```

Comment: This is exactly what I need, Thank you so much for your help with this.

Answer (score 0):

I encapsulated your input into a variable called `data`.

The problem you had was to format your data, not to insert into a SQL. So I'm leaving this up to you now :)

```
#   I see that my common characters to split my data is 2 following \n
groups = data.split('\n\n')
print(groups[0])
# Target: MicrosoftAccount:target=SSO_POP_Device
# Type: Domain Extended Credentials
# User: username
# Saved for this logon only

def format_group(group):
    """ Takes a group as input, and returns a properly formatted dict for the group.
    """
    resulting_dict = {}
    for line in group.split('\n'):
        split_pos = line.find(':')
        if split_pos > -1: # ':' is found, meaning it is not a comment but actual data.
            #   The data I have contains extra spaces and tabs, so I strip it.
            clean_key = line[:split_pos].strip()
            clean_val = line[split_pos+1:].strip()

            resulting_dict[clean_key] = clean_val

    return resulting_dict

#   Using my previously defined function for each group.
new_data = [format_group(group) for group in groups]

from pprint import pprint #Something to display nicely
pprint(new_data)
# [{'Target': 'MicrosoftAccount:target=SSO_POP_Device',
#  'Type': 'Domain Extended Credentials',
#  'User': 'username'},
# {'Target': 'MicrosoftAccount:target=SSO_POP_Device', 'Type': 'Generic'},
# {'Target': 'MicrosoftAccount:target=SSO_POP_Device',
#  'Type': 'Domain Password',
#  'User': 'domain\\username'},
# {'Target': 'LegacyGeneric:target=Slack/tokens',
#  'Type': 'Generic',
#  'User': 'tokens'},
# {'Target': 'MicrosoftAccount:target=SSO_POP_Device', 'Type': 'Generic'},
# {'Target': 'MicrosoftAccount:target=SSO_POP_Device',
#  'Type': 'Generic',
#  'User': 'domain\\username'},
# {'Target': 'MicrosoftAccount:target=SSO_POP_Device',
#  'Type': 'Generic',
#  'User': 'username token'},
# {'Target': 'MicrosoftAccount:target=SSO_POP_Device', 'Type': 'Generic'},
# {'Target': 'MicrosoftAccount:target=SSO_POP_Device',
#  'Type': 'Generic',
#  'User': 'username'},
# {'Target': 'MicrosoftAccount:target=SSO_POP_Device',
#  'Type': 'Generic',
#  'User': 'username'},
# {'Target': 'MicrosoftAccount:target=SSO_POP_Device',
#  'Type': 'Generic',
#  'User': 'domain\\username'},
# {'Target': 'MicrosoftAccount:target=SSO_POP_Device',
#  'Type': 'Generic',
#  'User': 'email address'},
# {'Target': 'MicrosoftAccount:target=SSO_POP_Device',
#  'Type': 'Generic Certificate',
#  'User': '<Certificate>'},
# {'Target': 'MicrosoftAccount:target=SSO_POP_Device', 'Type': 'Generic'},
# {'Target': 'MicrosoftAccount:target=SSO_POP_Device', 'Type': 'Generic'}]
```

Comment: Thank you for this. The comments are especially helpful. Although, I am going to be using the other method above as it's incorporating the blank comments section as well.

Comment: @cbrennan You can still upvote the answer if you found it helpful to you. :)